# Replace in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a column `A` in a table called `T`. The column is of type `nvarchar(255)`.

There is a trigger on this table that updates the values in column `A` to a column `B` in table `B`. The column `B` is of type `float`.

Suppose if there is value `35.1 %` in column `A`, I want to strip off the `%` and update only `35.1` in column `B`. It is not necessary that there should be a `%` symbol for the value in column `A`.

How do I do this in SQL Server 2008? Any ideas and suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Comment: How are tables T and B related? And does the trigger fire for updates or inserts on table T? Does it insert new rows into table B, or only update existing rows? What do you do when the value in T.A cannot be converted to a float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use the following query:

```
update B
set B.colB = cast(REPLACE(A.colA, '%', '') as float)
from A
where B.idB = A.idA
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '33.6' to data type int.COMMANDTEXT:UPDATE [InterestRatesLookup] SET [Category] = @@Category, [Term] = @@Term, [Value] = @@Title, [Modified] = @@Modified, [Created] = @@Created, [Created By] = @@Author, [Modified By] = @@Editor WHERE [ID] = 69

Comment: @SaiBand in this case you are trying to save '33.6' value to the integer column. In the question you where talking about B column that is of type float. Which column of *InterestRatesLookup* has float type?

Comment: What baffles me is that the column I am indeed trying to save is of type float. I don't where this INT is coming from.

Comment: or let's try another way around, which check which columns have type int

Comment: :Okay I was able to get rid of the error after checking the columns that have int.  However, if we I cast '33.6' as float using the above mentioned answer, I get 3. Am I missing anything.

Comment: great! if you try to use this statement, does it return correct answer? select cast('33.6' as float)

Comment: okay..the mistake I was doing was that I had the COL B a SET to just nvarchar(1) by mistake. I changed it to nvarchar(255), so now I get 33.6 set instead of just 3.

Answer (score 0):

`select replace('35.3 %','%','')` or `select replace('35.3 ','%','')` will both return `35.3`; just change your query accordingly; something like:

```
update tableb
set b=replace(valuefromcola,'%','')
where condition
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only numbers in a string try this function:

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[GetNumbersFromString](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

    While PatIndex('%[^0-9]%', @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex('%[^0-9]%', @Temp), 1, '')

    Return @TEmp
End
```

You should put this inside your trigger. Please note that you'll need to modify the function to accept the . and , characters (due to those being valid in numbers) =-)

Answer (score 0):

```
  --trim trailing non-alphanumeric chars  
 DECLARE @input nvarchar(4000) 
  SET @input = ',,, a word $$$'  

 SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@input), PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z0-9]%', REVERSE(@input)), LEN(@input)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update B
set B.colB = cast(REPLACE(A.colA, '%', '') as float)
from A
where B.idB = A.idA
```